# Broken pipe in Cassandra CLI when trying to update column family

Tags: cassandra, thrift

When I'm in the Cassandra CLI trying to make schema changes on a column family I get the exception:

update column family Stream with column_metadata = [{column_name: serverip, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type:KEYS}, {column_name: streamconnectioncount, validation_class: IntegerType}];

"org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe"

What is the proper way to make schema changes on Cassandra?

Comment: what version of cassandra are you using.

Answer (score 0):

That is a proper way. Are other stuff working against your column family?

Broken pipe is usually an indication that Cassandra cannot be reached, although I haven't experienced this from the CLI myself.